# Observer Communication Pattern

Tags: swift, observer-pattern, observers

I've a very easy implementation (3 classes) to get the basics. But it has Bug.

Facts: It notifies the ViewController, but the screen of the SecondVC it doesn't. Wonder why or where!

Git: https://github.com/marlhex/ObserverPattern

Relevant Classes:

```
struct MyNotifications {
    static let broadcast = "BROADCAST"
}
```

```
import UIKit

let notificationCtr = NotificationCenter.default

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        notificationCtr.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notifyObservers), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: MyNotifications.broadcast), object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func notifyObservers() {
        myLabel.text = "I got Notified"
    }
    
    @IBAction func doBroadcast(_ sender: Any) {
        notificationCtr.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: MyNotifications.broadcast), object: self)
    }

}
```

```
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mySecondLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        notificationCtr.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notifyObserverstoo), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: MyNotifications.broadcast), object: nil)
    }
   
    @objc func notifyObserverstoo() {
        mySecondLabel.text = "I got Notified too" //Bug only notifies one view controller
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a UITabBarController to host the views. The system initially only loads the view controller it needs to display (`ViewController` in this case). Then, once you click on the tab for the `SecondVC`, it loads that view controller.

You can verify this by putting a `print` statement in `viewDidLoad` of `SecondVC`.

You can also verify that if you navigate to `SecondVC` before going back to `ViewController` and pressing `Notify`, both view controllers get notified in this scenario.

So, it's not a bug -- it's just an implementation detail of when the views are loaded.

If you want to find a way to make sure that `SecondVC` has access to that information when it's loaded, you have two options:

1. Rely on a different system of propagating the state
2. Put your notification listener in `required init?(coder: NSCoder)` instead of `viewDidLoad` (this does get called during setup). **This has a caveat though**: the `UILabel` won't be loaded yet, so you'd have to store that state for loading later. Trying to access `mySecondLabel` before `viewDidLoad` will result in a crash.

**Update**
Updated code that stores the Notification in the event that you want to use the `init` method:

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var mySecondLabel: UILabel?
    
    var haveBeenNotified = false //to store whether the notification has been seen
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        notificationCtr.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notifyObserverstoo), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: MyNotifications.broadcast), object: nil)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Life Cycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("Loaded second view controller")
        
        if haveBeenNotified {
            mySecondLabel?.text = "Was notified before viewDidLoad"
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Observer Selector Functions
    @objc func notifyObserverstoo() {
        haveBeenNotified = true
        mySecondLabel?.text = "I got Notified too"
    }

}
```

Comment: I did ``` required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        notificationCtr.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notifyObserverstoo), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: MyNotifications.broadcast), object: nil)
    } ``` but nothing changed

Comment: I'm updating my answer with an example

Comment: Wow, until now I realized those calls, appreciate your time, effort, experience and attitude, bless!